# How do I set up a Snapshot space with a Gnosis multisig wallet?

Tags: walletconnect, gnosis, gnosis-safe, snapshot

I'm trying to set up a space on snapshot (https://snapshot.org/#/setup) with my gnosis multisig wallet. I connected with the gnosis wallet walletconnect app to snapshot and ENS but when I click confirm -- no pop up shows up.

Comment: Managing a snapshot space via a Safe is tricky, as off-chain message signing is not supported by the Safe interface.

Answer (score 0):

I am also begin to learn about this.

I joined the snapshot discord and got tip to follow the step by step guide in: https://gnosis.github.io/zodiac/docs/tutorial-module-reality/get-started/

We should install a plugin Zodiac Reality module.

Hope this help.